# PHP Define a class only allowed to be instantiated by another class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

Is there a way in PHP to make a class only allowed to be instantiated by another class? For example:

```
<?php 
    class Graph {
        private $nodes;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->nodes = array();
        }

        public function add_node() {
            $this->nodes[] = new Node();
        }
    }

    class Node {
        public function __construct() {
        }
    }
?>
```

In my example I want to prevent access to calling `new Node()` directly. Only access to `Node` should be  from the `Graph` class.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this?

Comment: it is pointless. I can see usecase were you have to be sure that you node is linked to a Graph, but why anything could not access to it? you want to make "private" classes like in java. But in PHP class has no visibility, like in C++.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do it. You can use a "hack" which consist in throwing an exception in the Node constructor if the argument passed to it is not a graph

```
class Node {
    public function __construct() {
        if(func_get_num_args() < 1 && !(func_get_args(0)instanceof Graph)){
           throw BadCallException('You can\'t call Node outside a Graph');
        } 
    }
}
```